# Python write to Excel with Sorted index

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, export-to-excel

I have written python code and I am trying to write a matrix into Excel.
I have created a dict in python and I use DataFrame to structure the matrix.
The problem is that, a dictionary in python can not be sorted. As such, when I write into Excel I get a matrix which is not ordered.

```
from pandas import DataFrame 
import pandas as pd

list = ['6M', '1yr', '2yr', '10yr', '30yr']

Corr = {}
for line in list:
    for line2 in list:
        ##  actual calculation is more complicated 
        ## I just show a simple example to illustrate the problem
        Corr.setdefault(line,{}).update({line2: 1})
    
df = DataFrame(Corr)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The output is like

[image]

which is not sorted by index.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, dictionaries in Python are not sorted. Fortunately, there's a module which can help - [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). From the docs:

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted

To use it, simply `import collections` and replace `Corr = {}` with `Corr = collections.OrderedDict()`

The dictionary will now preserve the order of entries and you can export this as you were doing before.

Comment: Thanks a million Aaron. It was very helpful.